# How to Google Search - limit results on specific domain extension?

Tags: google-search, domain-name

Is it possible to make a search which limits the search results to specific domains only i.e. `.org` (or any specific) extension?  Years ago, I remembered it was possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `site:` parameter:

```
mysearchquery site:.org
```

This will return all resuts containing `mysearchquery` which google finds on .org domains. Similarly, you can also do:

```
mysearchquery site:example.org
```

This also works in image, news, video searches.

EDIT - try this as search query: `google search specific sites site:superuser.com`